# Dynamic query creation (dynamic search engine)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iqueryable, entity-framework-4.3, dynamicquery

We are using ASP.NET MVC3, EF 4.3.1, DynamicQuery library
We are currently developping a dynamic search engine that could perform search query agains multiple database.

So we have an interface that allows the user to create a query.
Here is what the interface looks like this : [image: screenshot with selected ddl value]

So after that, we recreate the hierarchy of groups / clauses inside the controller and then we have to perform some joins between different tables (for example : Study / People).

The problem is that when we perform the joins, we do them as follow :

```
if (queries.ContainsKey("Drug"))
{
    query = query.Join(GetContext().StudyDrugs, s => s, sd => sd.StudyId, (s, sd) => new { Study = s, StudyDrug = sd })
                 .Join((IQueryable<int>)queries["Drug"], obj => obj.StudyDrug.DrugId, d => d, (obj, d) => obj.Study);
}
```

But then we can't set the Where clauses of the generated query since they don't always apply to the searched `IQueryable<T>` but on the joined objects.

And :
Since we need to be able to group clauses (that why we use groups in the screenshot), we have to be able to generate the Where clause correctly with the parenthesis. (this could be done with the PredicateBuilder class it seems but since the result of the search is an `IQueryable<T>`, we don't know if the where clause applies to the `T` class or one of the joined class.

Am I missing something ? Is there any tricks that could allow me to add the where clause after the joins have be done  but before the object are pulled from the database (still on the `IQueryable` object) ?

EDIT :

In fact, if I was able to specify the 'as' name in the generated SQL query, the ending where clause could be done pretty easily.
Is there any ways to name the joined table (T2 in the following example)?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 on (T1.T2Key = T2.Key)
```

Comment: I think you should match the predicates with the collections they apply to. If it is a joined collection: `.Join((IQueryable<int>)queries["Drug"].Where(...), obj => ...`

Comment: The problem is that the groups have been added because sometimes we have to do group the where clauses (using parenthesis in SQL). for example : X && Y OR Z can have different meanings : (X && Y) OR Z or X && (Y OR Z)... that's why the where clause should be applied at then end only but I don't know how.

Comment: What do mean it has to be applied at the end? Can you not parse the groups several times to build the where clause?

Comment: If you don't apply them at the end (all at once), you are not sure that your where clause reflect what the usere really entered (see pic) since applying a where independently doesn't give you the ability to generate a Where clause with parenthesis (in sql). I could indeed parse the groups several times but it is totally useless since I only need 1 big where clause to apply it correctly with `and` and `or. In fact, I need to generate the joins and once the joins are created, I can apply the where clause.